# JQuery Automatic Image Click

Tags: jquery, html, image

I'm not quite good in programming, but I can write basic stuff. 
How to click the image after 10 seconds using Jquery without adding any attributes into HTML?

HTML code:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="google">
   <img src="google.png" alt="Click here">
</a>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "click the image after 10 seconds"? Make the reaction delay?

Answer (score 0):

you mean like:

```
$(".google").find("img").delay(10000).trigger("click");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use setTimout()

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(".google img").trigger("click");
}, 1000)
```

or .delay()

```
$(".google img").delay(2500).queue(function(){
    $(this).trigger("click");
})
```

But remember none of this may trigger the default action, ie navigating to the other page because of browser restrictions

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function func(){
   $(".google > img").trigger("click");
}
setTimeout(func,10000);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to make the browser interpret your href only after it passed a certain time. You can get this by using a setTimeout function on the href of the link:

http://jsfiddle.net/gespinha/EBqy5/4/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.google').click(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        // link follow delay
        setTimeout(function() {window.location = href}, 10000);
    });
});
```